# Is there a way to refresh an element on page load with NiceGUI?

Tags: python, nicegui

I'm trying to build a web app with NiceGUI where the user can upload a file, and then be shown the contents of the file (or a message, any text as a label element really). It works fine, except that when I upload a second file, it keeps the old text (which actually makes sense when I think about it), and even if I refresh the page the old text is still there.

This is the code I wrote, and I was expecting that if the user refreshed the page, the labels created by `handle_upload` would disappear (similar to how the file upload element refreshes on page refresh and no longer shows the previously uploaded files).

```
from nicegui import ui, events
import os

ui.label("Upload File")
ui.label('(Drag and drop into the box below, or use the "+" button to select a file)')


def handle_upload(file: events.UploadEventArguments) -> None:
    ui.notify(f"uploaded {file.name} to {os.getcwd()}")
    data = file.content.read()
    with open(file.name, "wb") as f:
        f.write(data)
    lines = [line for line in data.splitlines() if line.strip()]
    ui.label("Lines uploaded:")
    for line in lines:
        ui.label(line.decode())

ui.upload(on_upload=handle_upload, auto_upload=True).classes("max-w-full")


ui.run(title="Submit File")
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, calling `ui.label` creates a *new* label and adds it to the page. To replace elements like a label with new ones, you can use a container and clear it before adding new elements. In the following example the container `output` is of type `ui.column` and is filled with the "Lines uploaded:" label as well as the file content:

```py
def handle_upload(file: events.UploadEventArguments) -> None:
    data = file.content.read()
    lines = [line for line in data.splitlines() if line.strip()]
    output.clear()
    with output:
        ui.label('Lines uploaded:')
        for line in lines:
            ui.label(line.decode())

ui.upload(on_upload=handle_upload, auto_upload=True)
output = ui.column()
```